# Can a controller function bind data to an element's data property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In jQuery, I'd do something like:

`var mySpan = $('<span/>,{ 'data':'somedata'});`

In Angular, I want to have a function that binds to that data property while in an ng-repeat runs in the DOM, for example,

`<div ng-repeat="item in items">
   <span ng-click = "someFunc(somedata)">{{somedata.someprop}}</span>
</div>`

So that I can access the object onClick in a ul and li based dropdown menu. I'm assuming I'm doing this the "wrong" (not Angular) way, but I can't see past it.

I know that I can use jQuery in the function, or the angular.element.data() method, but I can't seem to send that data to the function!

I'd prefer to not have the bound data visible as data-x, data-y tags in the html. That I can do just fine `<el data-x="{{somedata}}"></el>`

End result, I'd like to be able to call $(someEl).data() and get the data object that I've bound to it.

What am I missing?

Comment: I dont understand your question... what's your end goal? You can pass in params in the repeat or set a `data-*` attribute?

Comment: Just updated question

Comment: What object do you want to access onclick?

Comment: End result, I'd like to be able to call $(someEl).data() and get the data object that I've bound to it.

Comment: ng-click="somefunction(item)" will pass the item you want into your function

Comment: You're mixing Angular and JQuery - so that's probably going to cause a lot of headaches and weirdness.

Comment: On a side note - as @tymeJV is mentioning, you shouldn't be thinking of angular working the same way jquery does. Jquery is a great library but when you work with it you work with directly manipulating the dom. The angular methods of building do not work in the same way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If what you are looking to do is get access to the item a specific  is bound to in the click event, then the easiest way is just to pass it into the function invoked on ng-click:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <span ng-click = "someFunc(item)">{{somedata.someprop}}</span>
</div>
```